# redhat iso installation 64 bit on vmware player

Tags: vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, vmware-player

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUh8w.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeI2a.jpg)

I was trying to install red hat 64 bit iso ( rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-boot.iso ) on vmware player. But, I got stuck at the installation part itself. Though I have downloaded the 300+ MB iso, it is still asking me for the network location. Can anybody please help me in specifying the ISO location.

Moreover, I am not able to copy between vmwqare player and windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ramhound : The previous window to this page, would be the next screenshot that I am sharing as  of now. I am not able to select the ïnstallation source" and hence the installation is NOT beginning.

Comment: @Ramhound : Also, the copy paste between vmware player and windows is not happening. What to do for that?

Comment: @Ramound : the below is the link I have used to download the ISO. Link : https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/69/ver=/rhel---7/7.4/x86_64/product-software , it states that it is  a bootable ISO.

Comment: @Ramound : Can you please share the right link to download the complete ISO. I want to install openstack over red hat enterprise linux iso image.

Comment: @Ramound : for 30 days, an evaluation or trail copy is available/free

Comment: If you are trying to install RHEL on the VM, you want Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 Binary DVD, not the boot disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are downloading the incorrect ISO:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 Boot ISO
>
> A minimal boot image which can be used to boot the installation
>   program, but requires access to additional package repositories from
>   which software will be installed. Red Hat does not provide such a
>   repository; you must create it using the full installation ISO image.

You actually want the following ISO

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 Binary DVD
>
> A full installation image which can be used to boot the installation
>   program and perform an entire installation without additional package
>   repositories.

[Chapter 2. Downloading Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-download-red-hat-enterprise-linux.html)

Comment: I am running late for an appointment.  I will assume anyone with a subscription to RHEL can locate the correct download link and it doesn't require me to provide a link, to an asset, which will expired in a few months anyways.